# How to add a space after the 4th and 10th character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string consisting of 15 digits. For example, `347405405655278`. I need to add a blank space after the 4th digit and then after the 10th digit making it look like `3474 054056 55278`. Can I achieve this using a regular expression?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the help of regular expression, you can use the given below code to achieve the desired result:

```
var result = "347405405655278".replace(/^(.{4})(.{6})(.*)$/, "$1 $2 $3");
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution. I am trying to do something similar, but I need to add a space after each 3rd character counting from behind. This is for displaying a monetary amount. It should do something like this.  $1000 -> $1 000; $20000 -> $20 000; $3000000 -> $3 000 000 etc. (ignore the '$' in the expression please, I just need to format the number). Is this possible?

Comment: This was featured on the Stack Overflow podcast, [episode 349](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/22/podcast-349-the-no-code-apps-bringing-software-smarts-to-analog-services-disrupted-by-the-pandemic/), at 21 min 57 secs.

Answer (score 15):

Do it with substring concatenation:

```
var data = "347405405655278";
data = data.substr(0, 4) + " " + data.substr(4, 6) + " " + data.substr(10);
console.log(data);
# 3474 054056 55278
```

Or if you want to use regular expressions badly, then [as suggested by T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365092/how-to-add-a-space-after-4th-and-10th-character/23365142?noredirect=1#comment35787244_23365142),

```
var result = "347405405655278".replace(/^(.{4})(.{6})(.*)$/, "$1 $2 $3");
console.log(result);
# 3474 054056 55278
```

Comment: the second and third would be substr(4,6) and substr(10)

Comment: Or if you really, really want to throw rex at it: `var result = "347405405655278".replace(/^(.{4})(.{6})(.*)$/, "$1 $2 $3");`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. Included that in the answer :-)

Comment: substr() is now deprecated. Use substring() instead

Answer (score 1):

You can do search this:

`(.{4})(.{6})(.*)`

and replace with:

`$1 $2 $3`

This will match the first 4 characters, the next 6 characters and then the rest. The replace then replaces it with the 4 characters + space + 6 characters + space + the rest.

Comment: JavaScript uses $1 not \1 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @sshashank124: Frankly, due respect, it's still not all that useful with no context and no explanation.